# Unable to share YouTube videos to groups of users

Tags: youtube, google-workspace

We have a Google G Suite Basic account (company). I would like to share some videos to a group of users (a subset of domain accounts). Although I can share with individual users, there seems to be no way of group sharing. Any hints?

Comment: you need to create community space for your group first

Answer (score 0):

- go to **https://plus.google.com/communities**
- click on **+ NEW COMMUNITY**
- type in a name of a community group
- change policy from Public to **Private**
- press **<kbd>DONE</kbd>** button
- click on a share icon and invite people
- paste YouTube video link
- press **<kbd>POST</kbd>** button

[image: 9]
[image: 8]